# read() function error in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read from .txt file until I hit the character "=". Text file is always the same,contains only these strings:

```
TaskLimit=3
cc pr.c && ./a.out
```

Sometimes the code works fine and quits the while loop and sometimes it prints "TaskLimit" but then throws "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Should I clear the buf[] or something?

```
   char buf[1];

   file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
   if (file == -1){
      perror("Error opening file");
      exit(1);
   }
   while(1){
       read(file, buf, 1);
       if(buf[0]=='=') {printf("I'm out");break;}
       printf("%c",buf[0]);

   //further actions
```

edit:
in the "further actions" I'm trying to convert a char to int and this seems to be the problem:

```
char limit_char[0];
int limit;
read(file,limit_char,1);
limit=atoi(limit_char[0]);
```

edit2:
changing this line

```
limit=atoi(limit_char[0]);
```

to

```
limit=atoi(&limit_char);
```

helped.

Comment: How about checking if `read` call actually succeeds? And if it gives error, it might be useful to know what error.

Comment: I assume `plik` should be `file`? Please edit to fix that, too.

Comment: Anyway, you should provide a [mcve] in questions like this. There's nothing in the code you show, which would produce a segfault.

Comment: Unless you're doing, for example, non-blocking I/O, it is generally recommended that you use the C standard `fopen()` and associated functions rather than the POSIX `open()`

Comment: Not related to your problem: reading 1 byte at a time from your file is not a good idea.

Comment: @Toby I'm required to use POSIX functions in this project

Comment: @MichaelWalz Should I rather read the whole file to an array of chars? I don't have any other idea

Comment: Usually you read your files via a buffer, but if you use the `fopen`-family of functions you can use `fgetc` to read one character at a time and buffering will be handled by the library.

Comment: Just do not use `ato*()` as those functions does not provide complete error checking: `atoi("0");` and `atoi("any string not a number");` return the same result, namely `0` ... :-/!  Use the  `strto*()` family of functions instead!

Comment: this line: `char limit_char[0];` is wrong.  all it generates is a 'place holder'  it should be: `char limit_char[1];`

Comment: the function: `atoi()` is expecting a pointer to a NUL terminated string.  A much better statement would be: `limit = (int)limit_char[0];`

Comment: @hyde, actually there is a problem in the code.  I.E. the `atoi()` function is expecting a pointer to a string, not a individual char nor a pointer to an individual char.

Comment: @user3629249 That `atoi` code was added after my comment.

Answer (score 3):

The most important part of C programming is checking return values.

In your sample code sample you do it for `open(2)`, but not for `read(2)` and you should, because not only does it tell if there was an error, it also tells how many bytes have been read. Excerpt from the man page:

```
   On success, the number of bytes read is returned (*zero indicates end of file*),
   and the file position is advanced by this number.
```

That is, knowing that there is nothing more to read - return value of zero - can let you break from the loop in case the user gave you an invalid file.

When you learn C, I suggest (and pretty much every person on this site) to always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. C is a spartan language and mastering it requires discipline. GCC (or whatever your compiler is) would never have let you execute:

```
limit=atoi(&limit_char);
```

As the type of `&limit_char` is effectively `char **` and `atoi` expects a `const char *`.

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` requires a NULL-terminated array of char so your array needs 1 more element than you're reading in.

```
char limit_char[2];
int limit;
read(file,limit_char,1);
limit_char[1]='\0';
limit=atoi(limit_char);
```

beyond that, you should probably be checking the return value from `read` to make sure you've actually read something in.

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as `NUL`. You want `NUL` which is the `'\0'` character. `NULL`  is  a pointer value.

Comment: NUL is the name of the `'\0'` character in ASCII, but it's still called a NULL-terminated string https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string

Comment: In this context also `null` and  `NULL` are different. Please note the Wikipedia page *never capitalises* `Null` or `null`.

Comment: The *completely* capitalised `NULL` is defined by the C-Standard to be a macro evaluating to the "null pointer" (also well defined by the Standard using *exactly* this spelling), so consider its usage as "reserved" for exactly that.

Comment: This all sounds a bit picky, but being accurate here keeps everybody from misunderstandings, which might lead someone to do ugly stuff like `char s[42]; s[0] = NULL;` to terminate a C-string, which actually should be `... s[0] = '\0';` or just `... s[0] = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your code, your refer to `argv[1]` for the filename, but on the example usage (`cc pr.c && ./a.out`) you don't specify any filename.
2. In you `read()` statement you use a variable `plik` which is not defined anywhere, use `file` here, i.e. the variable you used to store the result of `open().

Fix this and it will work.

Comment: I'm not really worried about the further part of the txt file,I'm just trying to read the number after the "=" character first. I've already corrected the error,I copied this line from wrong .c file,sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This declaras an array of length zero which doesn't make much sense. BTW: normally the compiler should emit at least a warning.

```
char limit_char[0];
```

this wont work, you need an array of length 1 because you read 1 byte with `read`:

```
char limit_char[1];
```

or rather this:

```
char limit_char;
...
read(file, &limit_char, 1);
```